# ASP.NET. MVC 2 C#: So much whitespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

There a section of my code that is a mix between `<% %>` statements and HTML ... the view source is horrible. There is so much whitespace it makes me choke with disgust.

Is there anything I can do about this?

```
<!-- START Content -->
  <div class="divFilterWrap">

            <img src="/Content/Images/filterMainCuisineHeader.gif" />

            <ul>
            <% int count = 1; %>
            <% foreach (var filter in Model.Filter)
               { %>

               <% if (filter.GroupOrder == count) {
                  } else { %>

                    <% count++; %>

                    </ul>
                    <% switch (filter.GroupLabel)
                       { %>

                       <% case "Main Cuisine": %>
                       <img src="/Content/Images/filterMainCuisineHeader.gif" width="175" height="30" />
                       <% break; %>

                       <% case "Dining Style": %>
                       <img src="/Content/Images/filterDiningStyleHeader.gif" width="175" height="30" />
                       <% break; %>

                       <% case "Price Range": %>
                       <img src="/Content/Images/filterPriceRangeHeader.gif" width="175" height="30" />
                       <% break; %>

                    <% } %>
                    <ul>

               <% } %>

               <% if (filter.TagCount > 0) { %>

                    <% if (filter.TagChecked == 1) { %>

                        <li class="checked"><%: filter.TagLabel %> (<%: filter.TagCount %>) <span class="closeImage"><img src="/Content/Images/filterButtonClose.gif" /></span></li>

                    <% } else { %>

                        <li><%: filter.TagLabel %> (<%: filter.TagCount %>)</li>

                    <% } %>

                <% } %>

            <% } %>
            </ul>

  </div><!-- END Content -->
```

Where the C# code sits, that space is reserved when viewing source. And here is what it looks like:

```
<!-- START Content -->
  <div class="divFilterWrap">

            <img src="/Content/Images/filterMainCuisineHeader.gif" />

            <ul>


                        <li>Coffee / Tea House (1)</li>



                    </ul>

                       <img src="/Content/Images/filterDiningStyleHeader.gif" width="175" height="30" />

                    <ul>



                        <li>Casual Dining (1)</li>



                    </ul>

                       <img src="/Content/Images/filterPriceRangeHeader.gif" width="175" height="30" />

                    <ul>



                        <li>$8 to $15 (1)</li>


            </ul>

  </div><!-- END Content -->
```

GROSS!

Comment: If you have a look at stackoverflow's html source there's plenty of white space. Why is it a problem?

Comment: It's a problem because it's unecessary. It's a .NET curse that the page is no supressed when complied. Servers-side tags shouldn't reserve page source space. They are just rendering HTML in the end...

Comment: ...and the view source of stackoverflow is clean and normal.

Comment: Without you actually showing us what it looks like we have no frame of reference. So with that in mind: Your whitespace is atrocious and an affront to my delicate eyes. You need to completely redesign everything, STAT!

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question - ignoring the fact that the whitespace has little performance impact in any normal scenario, an explanation of what's going on has it's own value.

Comment: @dcolumbus: the server-side tags *aren't* reserving page source space, it's all the carriage returns you have outside your `<% %>` tags that are doing that.

Comment: @Carson, that does't make any sense. Where the HTML exists isn't the issue... it's the c# tags - the space all around the HTML - that is clearly the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, you are making a number of mistakes. The reason you have so much whitespace is that you're putting each C# code block on a new line. You don't need to do this. Have a look at my changes:

```
<img src="/Content/Images/filterMainCuisineHeader.gif" />
<ul>
<% int count = 1;
    foreach (var filter in Model.Filter)
    {
        if (filter.GroupOrder == count) {
        } else {
            count++; %>
        </ul>
        <% switch (filter.GroupLabel)
           { 
               case "Main Cuisine": %>
           <img src="/Content/Images/filterMainCuisineHeader.gif" width="175" height="30" />
           <% break; 
               case "Dining Style": %>
           <img src="/Content/Images/filterDiningStyleHeader.gif" width="175" height="30" />
           <% break;
               case "Price Range": %>
           <img src="/Content/Images/filterPriceRangeHeader.gif" width="175" height="30" />
           <% break;
           } %>
           <ul>
        <% }
        if (filter.TagCount > 0) {
            if (filter.TagChecked == 1) { %>
            <li class="checked"><%: filter.TagLabel %> (<%: filter.TagCount %>) <span class="closeImage"><img src="/Content/Images/filterButtonClose.gif" /></span></li>
            <% } else { %>
            <li><%: filter.TagLabel %> (<%: filter.TagCount %>)</li>
            <% }
        } 
    } %>
</ul>
```

You can see how I've removed a ton of your `<%` and `%>` and conjoined codeblocks together

Comment: Yes, I see... for some reason I have a fetish with closing my tags. Point well taken.

Comment: I believe this approach can actually be taken a step further. If you put yourself into the mindset that the normal content of your view is C# and not html, you can view %> as an opening tag for HTML content, and <% as the closing tag. In this way, you'd be more likely to have a single line like: 

%><img src="/Content/Images/filterPriceRangeHeader.gif" width="175" height="30" /><%

Answer (score 4):

Turn on GZIP compression in IIS.  The effects of white space in HTML are greatly reduced with GZIP compression on.

See for example: http://www.kwaree.com/blog/2009/11/27/how-to-remove-whitespace-from-html-code/

> "the removal of whitespace is not a
>   worthwhile endeavor. Any decent web
>   server is configured to use “gzip”
>   encoding for the serving of html
>   documents. The whitespace is readily
>   compressed and will be not
>   significantly change the amount of
>   data involved in serving the document.
>   While the end result will be smaller,
>   it will not be a nearly as large of a
>   gain as casual observation would
>   suggest."

Comment: I don't want to eliminate indetation... I want to eliminate the reserved space that the C# code seems to holding on to.

Comment: @dcolumbus - gzip doesn't remove anything, it merely compresses the response stream. I agree that in principle, I'd like there to be zero extra whitespace created by the view engine and rely on a smart client to format the source correctly when viewed, but the effects on the size of output are minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things. You could just delete the whitespace... multiple whitespaces aren't significant in either C# or HTML.

Or you could rewrite your view to use a view model DTO closely coupled to the structure of the page, so you're emitting pre-formatted fragments and rendering partial controls instead of having any complex control logic in your page code?

If you want to post your source, I'm sure there's ways to eliminate the whitespace if you *really* want to. But you're probably better off just ignoring it. :)

EDIT: OK, try this. Use a dedicated view model, so you can have your controller assign things like Image URLs in the controller logic instead of branching in the page code.

```
<img src="/Content/Images/filterMainCuisineHeader.gif" />
<ul>
    <% 
    int count = 1;
    foreach (var filter in Model.Filter) {
         if (filter.GroupOrder != count) {
            count++; 
    %></ul>
           <img src="<%=filter.ImageUrl%>" width="175" height="30" />
        <ul>
       <% 
    }
    if (filter.TagCount > 0) { %>
            <li class="<%=filter.CssClass%>">
                <%: filter.TagLabel %> (<%: filter.TagCount %>) 
                <span class="closeImage">
                   <img src="/Content/Images/filterButtonClose.gif" /></span>
            </li><%
       } 
    } 
    %></ul>
</div><!-- END Content -->
```

You'll need Model.Filter to be an IEnumerable, which looks like:

```
public class FilterViewData {
    public int GroupOrder { get; set; }
    public int TagCount { get; set; }
    public string CssClass { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string TagLabel { get; set; }
}
```

- something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) might prove very useful in populating your view data objects.

In this example, you'd also create a CSS rule like:

```
li.unchecked span.closeImage { display: none; }
```

so that the closeImage span and image don't appear inside the unchecked list items.

Does that help?

Comment: I think that's the answer right there... my view is dealing with the model data. It's in the view that I'm looping through the model data. You're suggesting that I should be doing my loops within partials so when the partial is compiled, it will eliminate the whitespace I'm experiencing?

Comment: See edits. A combination of properly-tweaked view data, streamlined markup and some cunning use of CSS can make your pages much cleaner without losing the structure and readability of the code.

Comment: I'm already using a ViewModel for this and a model... but when the page is rendering, I need to interate through the model contents. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an HTTP module to remove the whitespace.  Mads Kristensen has one:
http://madskristensen.net/post/A-whitespace-removal-HTTP-module-for-ASPNET-20.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example in your source:

```
        <ul>
        <% int count = 1; %>
        <% foreach (var filter in Model.Filter)
```

That's a lot of spurious whitespace after the `<ul>` (the indentation to your server tags).  You *could* rewrite it as:

```
        <ul>
<% int count = 1; %>
<% foreach (var filter in Model.Filter)
```

And adopt a style where server tags always begin on the line.  IMO, not worth it though -- I'd go with @Hightechrider's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a few bits of constructive points of improvement:

- escaping in and out of code/HTML far too much.

```
 <ul>
 <% int count = 1;   
   foreach (var filter in Model.Filter)
   { 
      if (filter.GroupOrder != count) 
      { 
           count++; %>
```

- you've got logic in your View. Consider moving that logic back into the controller. Your Model should have a property called GroupLabelImage, and the `switch` belongs in the controller. You should then write out the image just once.
- all calculations should be moved to the controller.

Comment: How can the model have a property GroupLabelImage when the image only changes once the group changes? That's the reason I'm using a switch. I'm checking to see if the GroupLabel has changed...

Answer (score 0):

To follow up my comment to @Alastair Pitts, (wiki because I just want to show formated example) I'm fairly certain that it's the whitespace between your HTML and the ASP.Net tags that is the real culprit, so starting with something like this is likely to look better when you view source (but it lacks something when it comes to readability in Visual Studio):

```
<img src="/Content/Images/filterMainCuisineHeader.gif" />
<ul><%
int count = 1;
foreach (var filter in Model.Filter) {
  if (filter.GroupOrder != count)
  {
  }
  else
  {
    count++; 
%></ul><%
    switch (filter.GroupLabel)
    { 
      case "Main Cuisine":
  %><img src="/Content/Images/filterMainCuisineHeader.gif" width="175" height="30" /><%
        break; 
      case "Dining Style":
  %><img src="/Content/Images/filterDiningStyleHeader.gif" width="175" height="30" /><%
        break;
      case "Price Range":
  %><img src="/Content/Images/filterPriceRangeHeader.gif" width="175" height="30" /><%
        break;
    }
%><ul><%
  }

  if (filter.TagCount > 0)
  {
    if (filter.TagChecked == 1)
    {
  %><li class="checked"><%: filter.TagLabel %> (<%: filter.TagCount %>)
    <span class="closeImage">
      <img src="/Content/Images/filterButtonClose.gif" />
    </span>
  </li><%
    }
    else
    {
  %><li><%: filter.TagLabel %> (<%: filter.TagCount %>)</li><%
    }
  }
}
%></ul>
```